# Can't create file in sd-card

Tags: android, file, bitmap, sd-card

I am trying to save a bitmap to a file and then saving it on sd-card.
Here's my code:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file = new File(path, "Jhs"+".jpg");
file.mkdir();
OutputStream fOut;
try {
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    BitmapMatrix convMatrix = new BitmapMatrix(0);
    convMatrix.result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);

    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also this code is in a class which does not extend Activity.I am just giving this information thinking that maybe there is some issue with this.
Here's my LogCat

```
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392): java.io.FileNotFoundException:           /mnt/sdcard/Jhs.jpg (Permission denied)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:66)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at com.example.imageprocess.BitmapMatrix.computeConvolution3x3(BitmapMatrix.java:123)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at com.example.imageprocess.MainActivity.sharpen(MainActivity.java:105)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at com.example.imageprocess.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
05-01 18:00:22.555: W/System.err(31392):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 18:00:22.565: W/System.err(31392):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
05-01 18:00:22.565: W/System.err(31392):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
05-01 18:00:22.565: W/System.err(31392):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 18:00:22.565: W/System.err(31392):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-01 18:00:22.565: W/System.err(31392):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
05-01 18:00:22.565: W/System.err(31392):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
05-01 18:00:22.565: W/System.err(31392):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Tom there's not much point in format editing an old question which was abandoned without meaningful resolution, and is most likely a duplicate of numerous others - all you end up doing is pulling it to the top of the page, distracting from questions which merit attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That logcat is saying you don't have permission to write the file,
Make sure you have declared

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in the android manifest.

You can add this:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath()+ "/%YOUR_FOLDER%/");
if (!(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory())) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

above your current code if you want to try a different folder location for the file and see if that helps.  The code will create the directory /sdcard/Downloads/YOUR_FOLDER/ in which you can create the file.  See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for storage location options.

You can then do

```
File file = new File(dir, "Jhs"+".jpg");
file.createNewFile(); //CREATE THE FILE FIRST!
OutputStream fOut;
try {
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ....
}
```

etc as in your post.

Comment: Are you sure the location you are trying to create the file exists in the file system? I have edited my answer to include code to check the directory exists and if not, create it

Comment: Also, try changing  "String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();" to "String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString().getPath();"

Comment: Just another thought, the device you're running to get the logcat doesn't have the sdcard mounted as external storage for the PC does it? That would cause permission errors. As would not having the sdcard mounted.

Answer (score 2):

Given the exception you are getting, you need to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:           /mnt/sdcard/Jhs.jpg (Permission denied)

Add this permission in Manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: You are placing file. so remove  `file.mkdir();` as it will create a directory and use `file.createNewFile()`

Comment: I have tried that also but still its showing me same error.I was trying if it was possible to create a new directory instead of a file.But the code is not at all working

Answer (score 1):

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Jhs.jpg (Permission denied)
```

It looks like you don't have [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) perimission.

Add this to your AndroidMAnifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```