# Read only file system android (is /mnt not /system)

Tags: android

Android device, I want to touch a file or dir in /mnt, it say "Read only file system", I don't know how to do. i try fix it with that fix /system, but it no work.

```
root@android:/ # ls -l
.....
drwxrwxr-x root     system            2011-01-01 11:33 mnt
.....
root@android:/ # 
root@android:/ # mkdir /mnt/test
mkdir failed for /mnt/test, Read-only file system
255|root@android:/ # 


root@android:/ # mount -o remount,rw /mnt
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
1|root@android:/ #
```

can't fix it as /system.
how can i do it?

```
root@android:/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)
root@android:/ #
```

But i can make directory in /mnt/xxx/, like this:

```
root@android:/ # mkdir /mnt/usb_storage/test                                   
root@android:/ # ls /mnt/usb_storage/test/                                     
root@android:/ # ls /mnt/usb_storage/                                          
test
root@android:/ #
```

---

**And**

i fond difference between /mnt and /mnt/usb_storage in init.rc

look /mnt:

```
# create mountpoints                                                            
    mkdir /mnt 0775 root system
```

look /mnt/usb_storage:

```
# Directory for multi usb storage                                       
mkdir /mnt/usb_storage 0700 root system                                 
mount tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/usb_storage mode=0755 gid=1000
```

Yes!I fix it!

create mountpoints

mkdir /mnt 0775 root system

add **mount tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/ mode=0755 gid=1000**

**now i can touch file or make directory in /mnt**

```
root@android:/mnt # mkdir /mnt/test
root@android:/mnt # ls -l /mnt/                                                
....
drwxrwxrwx root     root              2011-01-01 11:04 test
drwxrwxrwt root     system            2011-01-01 11:00 usb_storage
root@android:/mnt #
```

---

#### Resolved

ramdisk rootfs is read only.

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Answer (score -1):

you should have to add certain permission into your manifest file..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and for more see the following which near to what you looking for

[Can't create file in sd-card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318196/cant-create-file-in-sd-card)

Comment: no APP, i want to make directory with shell and in /mnt/ no /mnt/usb_storage

Comment: i fond difference between/mnt and /mnt/usb_storage in init.rc:mount tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/usb_storage mode=0755 gid=1000