# how to create directory inside /data on android

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a directory inside `/data` on an Android 10 platform. I've tried quite few things but now clueless. Appreciate any help/reference.

I've following `init.sample.rc` inside `/vendor/etc/init/`. I could see the print in `dmesg` but then no error.

```
on early-fs

    write /dev/kmsg "Creating sample directory structure..."
    mkdir /data/dir1 0755 root root
    mkdir /data/dir2    0755 root root
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920144/read-only-file-system-android-is-mnt-not-system) similar thread but it doesn't help me and still gives me following error. I also tried `on post-fs-data` after looking at `init.rc` but that too didn't help,

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
'/dev/block/dm-0' is read-only
```

I've also tried executing `mkdir ...` at the `adb shell` but it gave me following error,

```
# mkdir /data/dir1
# ls -lat /data/dir1    <--- EDIT1 - I overlooked this. it actually worked.
total 11
drwxrwxrwx  2 root   root   3488 2022-09-14 08:47 .
drwxrwx--x 50 system system 4096 2022-09-14 08:47 ..
# mkdir 0755 /data/dir1 root root
mkdir: '0755': Read-only file system
mkdir: '/data/dir1': File exists
mkdir: 'root': Read-only file system
mkdir: 'root': Read-only file system
```

Other things, I've in mind to try but don't know how,

1. mount / as read/write temporarily in the .rc file and create the directories
2. mount / as read/write permanently but I wonder which file it is done.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Read-only file system

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what you mean. I understand it is read-only and that's what I'm trying to learn with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much information available online when you are working with custom embedded platforms running android,

I hope following would help you someway but it is not at-all a complete answer.

1. Create `init.company.rc` at `vendor/company/common/rootdir/` with,

```
    on post-fs-data
        mkdir /data/sample 0777 system system
```

2. Modify `vendor/company/common/rootdir/Android.mk` with,

```
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE       := init.company.rc
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS  := optional
    LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := ETC
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES    := $(LOCAL_MODULE)
    LOCAL_MODULE_PATH  := $(TARGET_OUT_ETC)/init/
    
    # add soft link at the root
    LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD := \
        ln -sf /data/sample $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)/sample
```

3. Add `init.company.rc` to the build by chanfing the device make file,

```
    vendor/company/defs/product-defs/system/device.mk:
    PRODUCT_PACKAGES += init.company.rc
```

you may take a look at android documentation for creating a new device [here](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/new-device)